# Style individual elements inserted from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a table with data from API, but I am struggling to make this look nice... this is part of my code...

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.matches.length; i++) {
        let trow1 = document.createElement("tr");

        let td1 = document.createElement("td");
        td1.appendChild(
          document.createTextNode(`Round ${data.matches[i].matchday}`)
        );
        trow1.appendChild(td1);

        td1 = document.createElement("td");
        td1.appendChild(
          document.createTextNode(`${data.matches[i].homeTeam.name}`)
        );
        trow1.appendChild(td1);
        td1 = document.createElement("td");
        td1.appendChild(
          document.createTextNode(`${data.matches[i].awayTeam.name}`)
        );
        trow1.appendChild(td1);
        td1 = document.createElement("td");
        td1.appendChild(
          document.createTextNode(`${data.matches[i].score.fullTime.homeTeam}`)
        );
        trow1.appendChild(td1);
        td1 = document.createElement("td");
        td1.appendChild(
          document.createTextNode(`${data.matches[i].score.fullTime.awayTeam}`)
        );
        trow1.appendChild(td1);
        table1.appendChild(trow1);

        if (
          data.matches[i].score.winner === "HOME_TEAM" ||
          data.matches[i].score.winner === "AWAY_TEAM"
        ) {
          td1.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        }

        document.getElementById("outputgames").innerHTML = output1;
        document.getElementById("overallGames").appendChild(table1);
      }
    })
```

My goal is to have winning team in bolded text, but I need help.

```
if (
          data.matches[i].score.winner === "HOME_TEAM" ||
          data.matches[i].score.winner === "AWAY_TEAM"
        ) {
          td1.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        }
```

What shoud I do in this part of the code to have winning team's name in bold? This way I get last column of my code in bold, like you can see in this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/po7a9a

Also, back in my CSS file I have:

```
td {
  width: auto;
}
```

but how can I choose some individual td element? td:nth-child(x) is not what I need, because it changes everything across all tables.

Comment: Is this an exercise in trying to do it yourself or can you use an existing table library? No point in trying to recreate one by individually appending rows like this.

Comment: The problem is td1 is used over and over again. If you want to target a certain cell, you can not use the same variable for each new cell.

Comment: I understand, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to do this with appending elements is asking for trouble. Why not try mapping the data from the API and using template literals to construct the table? Additionally, classes are your friend! You can test for the winner or loser based off of the `match.score.winner` and set a class accordingly.

```
class="${match.score.winner == "HOME_TEAM" ? 'winner' : 'loser'}"
```

```js
const matches = [{"matchday":"9","homeTeam":{"name":"Geococcyx californianus"},"awayTeam":{"name":"Sylvicapra grimma"},"score":{"fullTime":{"homeTeam":3,"awayTeam":1},"winner":"HOME_TEAM"}},{"matchday":"9","homeTeam":{"name":"Vulpes cinereoargenteus"},"awayTeam":{"name":"Amblyrhynchus cristatus"},"score":{"fullTime":{"homeTeam":5,"awayTeam":0},"winner":"HOME_TEAM"}},{"matchday":"9","homeTeam":{"name":"Bucorvus leadbeateri"},"awayTeam":{"name":"Echimys chrysurus"},"score":{"fullTime":{"homeTeam":6,"awayTeam":5},"winner":"HOME_TEAM"}},{"matchday":"9","homeTeam":{"name":"Mungos mungo"},"awayTeam":{"name":"Choloepus hoffmani"},"score":{"fullTime":{"homeTeam":3,"awayTeam":6},"winner":"AWAY_TEAM"}},{"matchday":"9","homeTeam":{"name":"Castor fiber"},"awayTeam":{"name":"Procyon lotor"},"score":{"fullTime":{"homeTeam":6,"awayTeam":0},"winner":"HOME_TEAM"}},{"matchday":"9","homeTeam":{"name":"Bucephala clangula"},"awayTeam":{"name":"Chloephaga melanoptera"},"score":{"fullTime":{"homeTeam":4,"awayTeam":3},"winner":"HOME_TEAM"}},{"matchday":"9","homeTeam":{"name":"Canis mesomelas"},"awayTeam":{"name":"Toxostoma curvirostre"},"score":{"fullTime":{"homeTeam":3,"awayTeam":4},"winner":"AWAY_TEAM"}},{"matchday":"9","homeTeam":{"name":"Rhea americana"},"awayTeam":{"name":"Sciurus vulgaris"},"score":{"fullTime":{"homeTeam":5,"awayTeam":4},"winner":"HOME_TEAM"}},{"matchday":"9","homeTeam":{"name":"Epicrates cenchria maurus"},"awayTeam":{"name":"Graspus graspus"},"score":{"fullTime":{"homeTeam":7,"awayTeam":6},"winner":"HOME_TEAM"}},{"matchday":"9","homeTeam":{"name":"Bucephala clangula"},"awayTeam":{"name":"Spermophilus tridecemlineatus"},"score":{"fullTime":{"homeTeam":4,"awayTeam":5},"winner":"AWAY_TEAM"}}];

document.getElementById('outputgames').innerHTML = `<table class="table">
  ${matches.map(match => 
    `<tr>
      <td class="matchday">Round ${match.matchday}</td>
      <td class="name ${match.score.winner == "HOME_TEAM" ? 'winner' : 'loser'}">${match.homeTeam.name}</td>
      <td class="name ${match.score.winner == "AWAY_TEAM" ? 'winner' : 'loser'}">${match.awayTeam.name}</td>
      <td class="score">${match.score.fullTime.homeTeam}</td>
      <td class="score">${match.score.fullTime.awayTeam}</td>
    </tr>`
  ).join('')}
</table>`
```

```css
.winner {
  font-weight: bold;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
.name {
  color: #444;
}
.score {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id=outputgames />
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sven! To be honest, I learned 'my' way in one of the tutorials and I didn't look for better solution. Your code certainly looks much neater and better than what I have. I have another question now, as map is for arrays obviously and it works with matches array in your code, but I have data from API. data.map doesn't work and returns data.map is not a function, how should I fix this?

Comment: It should work with `data.matches.map` since that is what you want to be iterating over

Comment: Yes, but I get ReferenceError: matches is not defined
    at app.js:91
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at app.js:87

Comment: You must have the word "matches" used somewhere instead of data.matches because as far as your old code goes, there isn't a place where you're checking for matches being null, either. Could you paste what is on line 91 / 87

Comment: I am not sure where could I use matches...
This is the code starting from line 87, up to 91:
```
  .map(
    match =>
      `
      <tr>
      <td class="matchday">${data.matches.matchday}</td>
```
Above on line 86 is:
```
${data.matches
```

Comment: This is the screenshot, I can't format it in comments I guess: http://prntscr.com/pohkj6

Comment: so what map does is it takes an array and iterates over each element so that `match` element in that function is actually just a single element of that array. So when you're accessing that elements you just need to say match.score.winner. do not try to access the original array.